# How to filter by property components with searchable?

Tags: grails, lucene, searchable

i have two domain class like this :

```
class ExhibitionPrint {
  Exhibition exhibition
  Print print

  String title
  String description
  ....


  static searchable = {
      printSizes    component: true
      exhibition    component: true
}
}
```

And

```
class Exhibition {

String title
boolean isPublished
    ....
static hasMany = [exhibitionPrints: ExhibitionPrint]

static searchable = {  
    exhibitionPrints component: true
}
}
```

I used a closure in the search but it doesn't seem to work, I get results even when exhibition.isPublished is equal to false.
 I have something like this:

```
def searchResult = ExhibitionPrint.search{
must{
         queryString(query)
         term("ExhibitionPrint.exhibition.isPublished", true)
}
}.results
```

Any idea how to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you've created interprets to, essentially: `MUST match (query OR isPublished = true)`, or, using lucene's syntax `+(query isPublished:true)`

If I understand correctly, what you want is that it must match both clauses (that is:  `+query +ispublished:true`), so something like:

```
search {
    must(queryString(query))
    must(term("ExhibitionPrint.exhibition.isPublished", true))
}
```